# Django Eval from Database

Tags: python, django, eval

My group and I are trying to develop a "very-dynamic" web app with Django.
We have a "configurations" template for the users where everyone can configure his/her own space.
Every configuration option should be read from the DB.

view:

```
def config(request):
    if 'logged' not in request.session:
        return redirect(login)
    apps_list = App.objects.all()
    varS = varsesion(request)
    context = Configurations.objects.all()
    for row in context:
        row.form = eval(row.form) #Not sure at all if this is ok
        print (row.form)

    context.App = 'config'
    return render(request, "index.html", {'context': context, 'apps_list ': apps_list , 'varS': varS,
                                           'context.App': context.App})
```

And in our DB we have the `Configurations` model table like this:

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+---------+---------------+
| id |user |Title|Body |OptionBtn|     form      |
+----+-----+-----+-----+---------+---------------+
| N  |userA|  X  |  X  |    X    | DataConfig()  |
+----+-----+-----+-----+---------+---------------+
| N2 |userA|  X  |  X  |    X    | ColorsConfig()|
+----+-----+-----+-----+---------+---------------+
| N3 |userA|  X  |  X  |    X    |ButtonsConfig()|
+----+-----+-----+-----+---------+---------------+
```

And many other columns that I'll skip...

Of course every `Form` value in the DB's `form` field **exists in forms.py** with their respective names.
The problem comes when I try to **iterate these forms fields** in our template (every other column from the DB is displayed properly like buttons, titles, texts, etc)

Here is the template (I've skipped some of the attrs in the example table):

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
        <a href="/config.html"><h1 style="color:#871830">Configurations panel</h1></a>
    </li>
</div>
```

```
{% for configuration in context %}
<div style="" id="panel{{ configuration.codConfi }}" class="breadcrumb form-inline">
    <div class="form-group col-12" style="color:#228718"><h3>{{ configuration.title}}</h3></div>
        <div class="form-group col-3 m-1">
            <label class="form-group">{{ configuration.body }}</label>
        </div>
    <button id="btn{{ configuration.codConfi }}" type="submit" class="btn btn-info ml-auto mr-0 mr-md-3 my-2 my-md-4">{{ configuration.OptionBtn }}</button>
</div>
```

All this is displayed properly and perfect. But when it comes to the `form` DB colum...

```
<!-- _______________________Forms iterations__________________________ -->
<form style="display:none" id="frm{{ configuration.codConfi }}" class="breadcrumb form-inline" action="/Config/{{ configuration.codConfi }}" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group col-12" style="color:#228718"><h3>Configure {{ configuration.Title }}</h3></div>
        {% for field in configuration.form %}
            <div class="form-group col-3 m-1">
                <label class="form-group">{{ field.label }}: </label>
                {{ field }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ml-auto mr-0 mr-md-3 my-2 my-md-4">Apply changes</button>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

(If you see some attrs that are not showed in my example table it's just because I haven't typed all of them).

Instead of displaying the actual forms properly, it is displaying the value of `form` DB's column as a string. For instance, for the first value in `form` column (`DataConfig()`) it is displaying every letter as a string in the iteration (first it displays "D", then "a", then "t", etc until the last ")").
How can I tell Django it is not a String value but a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your Django model `Configuration` you could add a property that fetches and instanciates the actual form class.

For example:

```
class Configuration(models.Model):
    ...

    def get_form(self):
        # 'forms_module' is the Python module (file) that holds the form classes
        # 'self.form' is a string that holds the name of the form class
        form_class = getattr(forms_module, self.form)

        # create an (un-bound) instance of the form
        return form_class()
```

Then, in your template (assuming that `configuration` is an instance of the model `Configuration`) you can change this line:

```
{% for field in configuration.form %}
```

into this

```
{% for field in configuration.get_form %}
```

Note: for this to work, you will need to store the form class name without the parethesis in your DB field (or remove the parethesis before calling `getattr(forms_module, self.form)`).

---

If you need something more specific you will need to add more info to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't get what should I put in "forms_module", I tried by putting its form but I get an error "NameError at /Config/ name 'ConfigUser' is not defined" (ConfigUser is the form)

Comment: `forms_module` should be the python file that contains the definition of the forms. You have to import a reference to that python file in your code; for example, `from your_app import forms`

Comment: I could achieve what I tried here, many thanks! But one more question. I'm trying to get this form already filled with data. I noticed that in the method in the model I could do return form_class(instance=my_instance), and it works, but the problem is that I need to call it by a session variable, and they aren't allowed in models but only in views. How could I handle this?

Comment: `form_class(instance=my_instance)` is the correct way to get the form with data.

Comment: Where are you getting the instance of the `Configuration` model? You probably are getting that in your view to pass it to the template. In that same view you could try to call the method `configuration.get_form()` (using the instance from the session data) and pass the bound form to the template.

Comment: getting the instance in the view wouldn't have any sense for me in this case. Since the view dynamically calls every form from the DB, specifying instances for each form in the DB wouldn't be dynamic. I need to call its instance directly from the DB or from the form

Comment: It sound a bit complex and I'm having dificulties understanding your needs exactly. Maybe create a new question (since it seems to be a different problem than this question) with the relevant parts of your code.